# Moodle cog button on tests disappear in some courses

Tags: moodle

I was creating some courses for my moodle today when i realised that in some courses, the cog(settings) button on created tests completely disappear, this issue tend to affect some users more than others, sometimes one user has the cog button in the right up corner, others users don't despite having the same role and both beeing enrolled to same course, this seems completely random, i need to make sure that at least the teacher role aways have this button because teachers need to create test in my courses, how can i solve this problem?

Comment: Do you mean the cog and X settings for a user on a course level? The one besides "Active" or "Suspended" status?

Comment: yeah i already discovered the problem, since the new actualization the theme i was using started to get very buggy so when i tried a new theme the problem is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

i already discovered the problem, since the new actualization the theme i was using started to get very buggy so when i tried a new theme the problem is resolved.